# Guidelines to decide when a domain role needs to be explicitly modelled

Tags: domain-driven-design

I looking for some guidelines as to when one must explicitly model a role in the domain model.

I will explain my current stance with the help of an example here.

Say we are building a health care system, and the business requirement states

> "That only doctors with 3+ years of experience and certain
>   qualifications can perform surgeries"

In this case it is evident that the act of doing a surgery can only be performed by a person playing the role of a doctor and the doctor needs to meet certain prerequisites to perform the action

```
docter.performSurgery()
```

**So basically all doctors are not the same**

This method will probably check if the preconditions are met

So in the above cases, I will model the role explicitly.

Now lets consider the alternate scenario.

> Only a admin can approve of a funds transfer

In the above case I do **not** find any need to model this role in domain, as their are no rules distinguishing one admin from another in my domain.

Any person/userlogin with the permission of admin can perform this action, I would rather design this into my security infrastructure and ensure that the

`approveTransfer()` method invoked on the application layer is invoked only if the currently logged in user has the ADMIN permission.

So the *"domain model*" by which i mean classes like the Account class is unaware of this rule, this is codified in the application layer either via AOP or probably the AccountService class or the like.

What do the wise men have to say about this ? :)

Comment: In terms of the language used, and excuse the following as i don't know how the aggregates are structured, but would it not be `doctor.scheduleSurgery(date)`? From your post and function performSurgery it sounds like the system is doing the cutting!

Comment: I agree, we could debate on the language used as its not from a concrete use case, however the focus of the question was on when the doctor class (domain role) needs to be modelled and when it does not,

Answer (score 0):

When designing aggregates I always ask myself an important question.

- What is the consistency boundary for the process I'm attempting to model?

I ask what rules must be applied during any one atomic operation. This is referred to as a transactional boundary, and its your bread butter when defining your invariants (rules that must always be true during the lifetime of an atomic operation - start to end).

As I see it, the rule that a doctor/surgeon must have *n years of experience* - for a particular operation - is an invariant that must always be transactionally consistent (such as when performing a surgery). Therefor it should be modeled as a transactional boundary within a single aggregate.

Because aggregates can only guarantee the consistency within themselves, the invariants it is responsible for should not be leaked outside of it. In my opinion, and assuming that doctor is an aggregate, a separate roles model should not be responsible for an invariant that the doctor's model itself should be responsible for.

Aggregate to aggregate relationships should really only be established to provide 'help' in giving some missing piece of information. But the rules and how that information is interpreted should be isolated within its respective aggregate.

A separate situation can arise for user authentication. You may have a bounded context with a `Customer` model, but the details of permissions, authentication, and roles are so vast as to require an entirely separate system to deal with. In this case you may end up creating a separate bounded context for `User Roles and Permission` and linking the two bounded contexts. In this scenario you could have a domain service that deals with the communication between the two. Call the `Customer` root with an operation and pass in the domain service for some intention revealing double dispatch and let the domain service resolve wheather that operation goes through or not. In this scenario though, the responsibilities of user auth is not the `Customer`'s at all. The `Customer` simply doesn't care (because it cannot itself guarantee the transaction) and its up to `User Auth and Roles` to decide what to do.

From: Implementing Domain Driven Design - *Vaughn Vernon*

> A properly designed Aggregate is one that can be modified in any way required by the business with its invariants completely consistent within a single transaction. And a properly designed Bounded Context modifies only one Aggregate instance per transaction in all cases. What is more, we cannot correctly reason on Aggregate design without applying transactional analysis.